# Define a STL structure for implementing a glossory?

Tags: stl

In an interview I got a question like:

"define a structure using STL like list, vector, map etc. to implement a **Glossary** that you find at the end of any book."

Any ideas how could I define a structure for Glossary.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

STL's `Map` container would be fine for this. There's no need to create your own.

Are you sure the question wasn't `Which container would be best`?

Comment: No, he just asked me to give my thoughts on the implementation of the glossary. AS you know glossary contatins words alphabatically with page numbers. There might be same word in multiple pages also. So how would you do using Map container?

Thanks...

Comment: A glossary contains word/phrases and definitions (and sometimes page numbers). An index contains words and page numbers.

Answer (score 0):

A glossary would normally contain a word and a definition of that word. For this, an `std::map<std::string, std::string>` should do the job quite nicely.

Based on your comment, you may be looking for something closer to an index, with a word and a number of pages in the book where that the word is used. In this case, you could use either an `std::multimap<std::string, int>`, or something like an `std::map<std::string, std::vector<int> >`. Given the way an index would usually be printed (the word shown only once, followed by all the page numbers where that word is used) it's probably easier to use the latter for this case.